# tag to describe html, css, javascript, jquery...?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm creating a portfolio which will show a short summary of the projects. One of these titles would be the technology used. So I got to this doubt...

Can you call html, css, javascript, jquery, php... as software? I know that photoshop, flash etc are software but I'm not sure of html, css... So, what kind of tag would you use to describe them in one word?

Comment: How about "Web Development"? EDIT: I guess that's two words. :\ Just "Web", then?

Comment: I'd use "Technologies" or just throw software etc at one pile: "Tags: jquery php flash", for example. And why would you mention "HTML"? Every project involving websites would receive that tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these are not types of software. Software is what you would use to code these.

I would describe them as **[client-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) and [server-side scripting languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting)**

Comment: What if I mixed them? So if in the same field I would place html and photoshop for example? I have in my mind technique but maybe there is an official term

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero It depends on how you're using photoshop really. If you're designing a web application, then this would be grapic design, but if you are simply cropping or resizing images, then this wouldn't count...

Comment: using photoshop for design of course. IF it was only for cutting I wouldnt put it

Answer (score 1):

Technically they're languages, not software. That's what I'd list them as, though I'm not sure how that would fit in with any design/layout you already have in place...

Comment: Ummmm, I see that if I wanted to be completely strict I would have to separate them in different tags. I could use general terms as technology for example... This way I could place software and languages together.

Answer (score 1):

The names you've just mentioned are scripting languages (as opposed to programming languages).

Front-end/Client Side: html, css javascript & jquery

Back-end/Server Side: php